# How do I troubleshoot repository issues? Many problems lately

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, repository

For several months now I've been having some problems installing packages on Ubuntu 18.04. I've been on Ubuntu for well over a decade now and while there have been  occasional, transient hiccups with repos, those were intermittent and short-lived. This seems (!) to be something different.

Firstly, packets that Ubuntu tells me I need don't seem available. For example:

```
me@host:~$ cwebp

Command 'cwebp' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install webp

me@host:~$ sudo apt install webp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package webp
```

Then there are dependency issues. For example:

```
me@host:~$ sudo apt -f install ufraw
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ufraw : Depends: libgtkimageview0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Looking for held packages reveals none; `me@host:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` lists no packages at all.

The above are only two examples; I've had these problems with multiple packages. It might of course be possible that I've had the unlikely misfortune of requesting a bunch of broken packages over the past few months. Some packages still do install properly (i.e. not everything fails). But if this is a repo issue, I'd expect it would have been noticed and fixed by now, I'd imagine. I've never had this before, but lately it's becoming more and more frequent.

I have switched mirrors, tried downloading from the main repo, a `dpkg –configure -a` and using the `-f` switch on apt, all with no effect whatsoever.

What else can I do to try and troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: A quick command (`rmadison webp`) and I can see the package is available for supported releases (and ESM, *dev* etc), but I don't know your release. It's located in 'universe' so do you have that repository available?  (if you haven't installed tools like `rmadison` you can use packages.ubuntu.com too).  Knowing your release details is a start for package issues. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  (we can't be specific until given that detail either)

Comment: As stated above, my release is Ubuntu 18.04. Or isn't that what you meant? In "Software and update settings" I have selected the main, universe, restricted and multiverse repositories; download from Main Server.

Comment: Yes you did mention 18.04, so sorry I missed it.  I would then view your `sudo apt update` to ensure you have no issues, and check your mirror is *up-to-date* (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) though you implied that not being your likely issue. I would take note of when it occurs; ensure no local network issues (esp. if on restricted network such as corporate/university/etc).  Your first paste reads like user error (issues ignored with `sudo apt update` before the command was done, or typo like your pasted command shows)

Comment: Also, when installing ufraw or gimp-ufraw, this requires 'libgtkimageview0' which, according to apt, has no installation candidate.

Comment: For *bionic* I see `libgtkimageview0 | 1.6.4+dfsg-2          | bionic/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` so in that case I'd assume you have an issue with your sources (read `sudo apt update` output & look for clashes, missing details, and or inappropriate 3rd party sources). We can't help much without full messages.

Answer (score 0):

Motivated by the comments above I finally decided to try a whole lot of different mirrors. Strangely, quite a few turned out to generate error messages during `apt update`(incorrect file sizes or hashes), even the `Main Server` and the `Server for United States`(as listed in the `Software settings and updates` GUI).

I finally ended up using `ubuntu.mirror.rain.co.za` which appears to be error-free. Now my packages install properly and without problems.

So it *was* an issue with the repo mirrors I was using! Strange, though, that so many of them appear to host broken packages for months on end.